# jquery load part of page, select by variable ID

Tags: jquery, load

I am trying to load a portion of a page using jquery .load(), the the problem is, the div that I am trying to select is a variable

```
$('#additemsubmit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var location = $(this).parent();
    var reload = '#' + $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $(location).load("/index.php reload");
});
```

It seems I cant use variables for "location" and "reload"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
 var reloadId = '#' + $(this).parent().attr('id');
 $.get("/index.php", function(response) {
     $(location).html($(response).find(reloadId));
 });
```

Comment: but how would I load just a portion of index.php, specifically the div that == var reload

Comment: @livinzlife: You need to concatenate strings.

Comment: how would I use a callback to strip index.php of everything except for the reload div (keep in mind, reload is a variable, not a static #reload)

Comment: @adamrackis This does work to reload the div as I wanted, but for some reason, the buttons/checklist inputs dont run the functions that they do BEFORE reloading. Any hints?

Comment: @livinzlife - yes - wire your click handlers with `on` - then dynamically added content will continue to fire those handler

Comment: @adamrackis So instead of having my click function after $(document).ready(), I would have to have an "onclick="" for each item within the body that is going to be reloaded? I currently have many functions running in $(document).ready(), none of which apply after the content has reloaded. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @livinzlife No - In your document.ready, instead of saying `$(".buttonClass").click(function...` you'd say `$(document).on("click", ".buttonClass", function`  - check the jquery docs for more info on how to use on

Comment: @adamrackis you are the man, all goals accomplished. Thank you for helping beyond the original question!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use string concatenation to pass a selector to `.load()`:

```
$(this).parent().load("/index.php#" + $(this).parent().attr('id'));
```