# ZendFramework: Load a part of phtml per Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

It's possible to get a part of a phtml per Ajax?
The phmtl is a form and I just need to load a part of this form dynamicly.
Zend Version 1.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phtml files are layouts and they should not be accessible directly. 
The best practice is create an action in a pertinent controller and render the form layout from there.

After you can use jQuery.load() like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8584770/487334

Comment: OK. Thanks. Taht could help